# json_decode a nested array/object

Tags: json, twig

I have received a JSON payload for an order / abandon cart in this format.

```
{
    "tokens": {
        "locale": "en_GB",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "entity_id": "36140",
        "item[0].type": "straw",
        "item[0].row_total_incl_tax": "2000.0000",
        "item[0].quantity": "2.0000",
        "item[0].name": "Diego",
        "item[0].straw_type": "itri",
        "item[0].mot": "20",
        "item[1].type": "virtual",
        "item[1].row_total_incl_tax": "625.0000",
        "item[1].quantity": "1.0000",
        "item[1].name": "Mixmatch",
        "item[2].type": "straw",
        "item[2].row_total_incl_tax": "1000.0000",
        "item[2].quantity": "1.0000",
        "item[2].name": "Diego",
        "item[2].straw_type": "abc",
        "item[2].mot": "20",
        "item[3].type": "straw",
        "item[3].row_total_incl_tax": "600.0000",
        "item[3].quantity": "1.0000",
        "item[3].name": "Pete",
        "item[3].straw_type": "itri",
        "item[3].mot": "20"
}
}
```

I can print values like tokens.entity_id - this works successfully.
However, for each of the Items e.g. item[0] I want to pull the item.name to print using Twig and can't seem to make this work.

I have tried several things e.g.

```
{% set cart = contact.json_field | json_decode %}
{% for tokens in cart %}
Entity  : {{tokens.entity_id | raw }} <br>


{% for item in tokens %}
Item Name : {{item.name | raw }} <br>
{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

I have also tried tokens.item.name, and tokens.item1.name, and tokens.item[1].name but never seems to be able to pull the values for the items.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm new to Twig

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this, by restructuring the json data

```
<ul>
 
Item Name : {{tokens.entity_id | raw }}
{% set count = 0 %}
{% for item in tokens.items %}


{% set counter = ( counter | default(0) ) + 1 %}
{% set test = tokens.items.1.type %}
{{counter}}

Item Name : {{tokens.items.1.type | raw }}
Item Name : {{tokens.items.1.row_total_incl_tax | raw }}
{% endfor %} 
</ul>
```

json

```
        "link_order_status": "http://testing.com/en/",
        "items": {
            "0": {
                "type": "straw",
                "row_total_incl_tax": "400.0000"
            },
            "1": {
                "type": "testing #1",
                "row_total_incl_tax": "300.0000"
            },
            "2": {
                "type": "testing #2",
                "row_total_incl_tax": "200.0000"
            }
        }
```